# How to set laravel's api with apache when installed in a different folder of DocumentRoot

Tags: laravel

Now I have a site, frontend(vue, html) and backend(laravel 10) is separate.

DocumentRoot is:

```
D:\Web\example.org\public
```

This is all laravel files:

```
D:\Web\example.org\laravel  
    \app
    \bootstrap
    ....
    \public
    ....
```

I made a soft link

```
cd D:\Web\example.org\public
mklink /D laravel D:\Web\example.org\laravel\public
```

Now I have

```
D:\Web\example.org\public\laravel
```

Which is just a link to

```
D:\Web\example.org\laravel\public
```

.env

```
APP_URL=laravel.test
```

Then I visit

```
http://laravel.test/laravel
```

Ok, the laravel's defalut page, good.

**But now I want to use api, doesn't work.**

```
mklink /D api D:\Web\example.org\laravel\public\api
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'hello';
});
```

Url:  http://laravel.test/api
I expect it give me 'hello', but 'Forbidden' page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Create file:
**D:\Web\example.org\public\.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ laravel/api/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And it works.